# How to show french special characters in wordpress url?

Tags: wordpress, url, character-encoding

How can I keep in wordpress in the urls of the posts the name post which has special characters? For example [http://example.com/été](http://example.com/%C3%A9t%C3%A9)?
When I try to save the post it saves the url /ete instead of /été. 
In the previous site in druplal this wasn't an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**URL** means **Uniform Resource Locator** and it uses ASCII encode. This means that all special characters are replaced by %nn where nn is a number since they don't belong to ASCII standard.

The answer is that this is not possible and you can refer to this link to [learn more about url](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: in drupal it works why shouldn't it work in wordpress?!

Comment: You can have a look to [this post in the wordpress support community](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/special-characters-in-url-1)

Comment: Are you using the free version of Wordpress or the PRO? It could be that you can use some plugin or make some php fixes, but in the free version it seems to be not possible

Comment: DId you find anything else usefult or it might be consider a final answer?